# Woocommerce - display different product thumbnails on category page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook

I would like to display a different thumbnail for some of my products, if they appear in specific categories.

I have removed the current thumbnails from the specific category and I am using a custom field to pull the new thumbnail for the products I want to replace, which is working great. However, when I try to call the normal thumbnail for the remaining products it doesn't work - any ideas?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'remove_test_category_thumbnails', 10 );

function remove_test_category_thumbnails() {
    if (is_product_category('test-category')) {
        remove_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' , 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail' , 10);
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'add_test_category_thumbnails', 10 );

function add_test_category_thumbnails() {
    global $post;
    $testCatThumb = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'step_dad_mug', true);
    if (is_product_category('test-category') && (isset($testCatThumb)) ) {
        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $testCatThumb );
    }
    else 
        echo woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail();
    }
}
```

Comment: The `isset()` check alone is not enough. If the `$testCatThumb` variable returns an empty value, `isset($testCatThumb)` will return true because it only checks if the variable is declared and is not NULL. In your case you should also add `! empty ($testCatThumb)`. So the if statement could be: `if ( is_product_category('test-category') && ( isset($testCatThumb) && ! empty($testCatThumb) ) ) {`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have tried your code and it seems to display original thumbnails but not the one I want to replace. Any ideas?

Comment: There are two options: you are not in the product category page with a `test-category` slug, or the product does not have the `step_dad_mug` custom post meta.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `echo` the `woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail`. check below code.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'remove_test_category_thumbnails', 10 );
function remove_test_category_thumbnails() {
    if (is_product_category('test-category')) {
        remove_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' , 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail' , 10);
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'add_test_category_thumbnails', 10 );
function add_test_category_thumbnails() {
    global $post;
    $testCatThumb = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'step_dad_mug', true); 
    if( is_product_category( 'test-category' ) && ( isset( $testCatThumb ) ) ) {
        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $testCatThumb );
    }else{
        echo woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I must have missed this off as I have been trying lots of different variations to try and make it work however, adding echo doesn't resolve it.

Comment: I have tested it on my site and it is displaying the new thumbnail on products with the custom field (correctly) but the products without the custom field it doesn't display the product thumbnail.

Answer (score 0):

The following function expects a post id, is that what you are passing it?

```
wp_get_attachment_image();
```

as part of your if condition, you could check the value is of the correct value type:

```
is_numeric($testCatThumb);
```

I tend to create readable variables, rather than having horrible conditions you have to parse with your brain every time you read it:

```
function add_test_category_thumbnails() {
    global $post;

    $testCatThumb        = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'step_dad_mug', true);
    $isPostId            = !empty($testCatThumb) && is_numeric($testCatThumb);
    $isValidAttachmentId = is_product_category('test-category') && $isPostId;
    $image               = $isValidAttachmentId ? wp_get_attachment_image($testCatThumb) : '';

    // display custom image, or fallback to woocommerce thumbnail
    echo !empty($image) ? $image : woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail();
}
```